# scripts stop working after jquery replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, soundmanager2

So i have a form which i submit using jquery post method, and replaceWith the content of the division with the ajax returned data. Here is the code:

```
    $(".filter_field").change(function() {
        $.post("/business/feedbacks/", $("#filter_form").serialize(),
            function(data) {
            $('#table-content').replaceWith($('#table-content', $(data)));
            });
    });
```

Now i am facing two problems with this method:

1) I am also using a reset button which just reset the form's fields values to initial values and then trigger the change event like in the following code:

```
      $('#filter_reset').click(function () {
            $(':input','#filter_form')
            .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
            .val('')
            .removeAttr('checked')
            .removeAttr('selected');
            $(".filter_field").trigger('change');

      });
```

Now whenever i click the reset button, it resets the form's fields and submits the form using ajax via a change event described above. So far so good, but now i am unable to trigger the change event anymore. Now matter which field i click on now in the form, it just doesn't submit the form anymore using ajax.

2) I have a soundmanager plugin installed in the #table-content division (multiple instances of it). Now after the ajax submit, that soundmanager plugin stops working, because i assume, as the soundmanager is loaded at ready event, it does not execute after the ajax submit and replaceWith, hence it stops working.

Any solutions to circumvent these issues? I am new to query, so sorry if i am doing the things wrongly, please guide me in right direction. Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit: It turns out that if i include $.getScript("/static/js/360player.js"); it works properly. Isn't there a method to attach the events to the elements replaced with using jquery replaceWith command. 'On' event doesn't seem to work at all.

Edit2: It turns out that i was using 'on' on a wrong division. My bad :(

Comment: I think you need a close parentheses after the 'table-content' on this line: `$('#table-content').replaceWith($('#table-content'), $(data));`

Comment: It produces the undesired effects. The way i have written seems to produce what i want.

Answer (score 0):

When you replace the elements you also remove any attached event handlers.  You need to use delegation to bind the event handler to existing elements *and* future elements...

```
$("body").on("change", ".filter_field", function() {
    $.post("/business/feedbacks/", $("#filter_form").serialize(),
        function(data) {
        $('#table-content').replaceWith($('#table-content', $(data)));
        });
});
```

Not sure about your second issue, but it sounds like a similar approach is required for that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this solution did not solve my problem :(

Comment: It depends on jQuery version though. Prior to 1.7, you have to replace `on()` with `live()`.